# Cast type as specific MyCollection<MyType> and call method on it via Reflection

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

I have a custom collection type `ObservableStateCollection` that, for simplistic purposes, looks like:

```
public class ObservableStateCollection<T> : IList<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged where T : StateObservable
{
    private List<T> _items;
    private List<T> _deleted;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerable<StateObservable> GetAll()
    {
        return _items.Concat(_deleted);
    }

    //...
}
```

Note that type `T` must be derived from `StateObservable`.

Now, I'm neck deep in reflection.  I'll spare the details of 'why', and just show you where I'm currently at.  I need to check if a particular property on my model *is* an `ObservableStateCollection<T>` and use a foreach to loop through the `GetAll()` method.

Currently, I'm at:

```
 if(prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObservableStateCollection<>))
 {
       var collection = (ObservableStateCollection<StateObservable>)prop.GetValue(model, null);
       foreach (var e in collection.GetAll())
       {
            //act on ObservableStateCollection<StateObservable>                      
       }
 }
```

which throws an exception on the line `var collection = ...`, as I can't cast `ObservableStateCollection<DerivedType>` to `ObservableStateCollection<BaseType>`

What are my options here?  How to I get a strongly typed object back that I can call `GetAll` on?

Answer (score 0):

ahh got it.  I invoked `GetAll` via reflection.  Not sure why that didn't occur to me at first:

```
if(prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObservableStateCollection<>))
{                        
     MethodInfo m = prop.PropertyType.GetMethod("GetAll");
     var collection = m.Invoke(prop.GetValue(model, null), null);

     foreach (var e in (IEnumerable)collection)
     {
         \\act on item in collection                      
     }
}
```